# HTML Dropdown to Datalist - Screen load/rendering performance

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, html-datalist

I have an HTML page that displays about 500 line items with each row allowing a template selection from a dropdown with 450 options to choose from. The page takes about 90 seconds to complete loading in IE 11 and about 60 to 70 seconds in Chrome/Firefox. The server/J2EE portion of the code completes in about 3 seconds. The delay in HTML rendering makes this page super slow.

Answer (score 0):

**Issue**: Delay in HTML rendering, 60 to 90 seconds
**Root-cause**: Rendering delay [super long HTML page, approx 250,000 lines of HTML code]
**Resolution**: Replaced the drop-down option with datalist and page loads in under 5 seconds. HTML code reduced to approx 50,000 lines.